# Prefix in front of input line

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, input, command-line-interface

I want to have a prefix in front of input blocks just like python has:

> ```
> E:\Users\foobar\Downloads\KahootTest1>py
> Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul 8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>
> ```

When I write `console.log(">>>")` It automatically starts a new line so I can't type on that one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` is just use to show something, not to read an input. If you use `node.js` you will have to use the [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync) package to read user input and you can give it a string that will be show on the cli:

```js
// First install package: 'npm i readline-sync'

var readline = require('readline-sync');

var line = readline.question(">>> ");
```